# Problem executing Mac app created using tkinter and py2app due to incorporation of plotly.express

Tags: python, tkinter, plotly, py2app

I'm creating a Mac App using tkinter and py2app and am encountering problems when trying to incorporate plotly.express. (Python 3.7 on Mac OS 10.15.4)

The app asks the user for the time series length and overlays the plots of three random time series using that specified length along with the labels, 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry,
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

window = Tk()
plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')

window.title("Plotter")
window.geometry('500x500')

length_label=Label(window, text="Length")
length_label.grid(row=0,column=0)

length = Entry(window,width=20)
length.grid(row=0,column=1)


'''Plot time series'''

def _plot():
    np.random.seed(123)
    num_times=int(length.get())
    X = np.random.randn(num_times,3)  
    df=pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['a','b','c'])
    df['x'] = df.index
    df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars="x", value_vars=df.columns[:-1])
    fig=px.line(df_melt, x="x", y="value",color="variable")
    fig.show()    

plot_button = Button(master=window, text="Plot", command=_plot)
plot_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

'''Quit Button'''
def _quit():
    window.quit()
    window.destroy()

quit_button = Button(master=window, text="Quit", command=_quit)
quit_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Everything works fine to this point.

Using py2app, I'm able to follow the usual steps for creating the application:

```
py2applet --make-setup myapp.py
rm -rf build dist
python setup.py py2app -A
```

The file runs from the terminal via 
    ./dist/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp

I then deploy the app via
    python setup.py py2app

The resulting app on my desktop opens when I double-click. It accepts my "length" entry. After hitting the plot button, however, nothing happens. I should see a graph in my browser window.

I did notice that everything worked fine (even when double-clicking the app) if I replaced

```
df['x'] = df.index
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars="x", value_vars=df.columns[:-1])
fig=px.line(df_melt, x="x", y="value",color="variable")
fig.show()
```

with the simpler

```
plt.plot(df)
plt.show()
```

Of course, now the plot merely opens in a new window. I lose the nice interactive features of plotly.express, e.g. zooming, panning, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because I wish to create an interactive plot from a pandas data frame, I used the igraph command in cufflinks package as opposed to plotly.express. As the cufflink documentation at https://plotly.com/python/cufflinks/ points out, "By passing the asFigure=True argument to .iplot(), Cufflinks works similarly to Plotly Express..."

My code now looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry,Label
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks

window = Tk()
window.title("Browser Plotter")
window.geometry('500x500')

length_label=Label(window, text="Length")
length_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
length = Entry(window,width=20)
length.grid(row=0,column=1)


'''Plot time series'''

def _plot():
    np.random.seed(123)
    num_times=int(length.get())
    X = np.random.randn(num_times,3)  
    df=pd.DataFrame(X, columns=['a','b','c'])
    fig=df.iplot(asFigure=True,xTitle='time',yTitle='values',title='Time Series Plot')
    fig.show()

plot_button = Button(master=window, text="Plot", command=_plot)
plot_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

'''Quit Button'''
def _quit():
    window.quit()
    window.destroy()

quit_button = Button(master=window, text="Quit", command=_quit)
quit_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

I also updated my setup.py file so to include

```
'packages':'cufflinks'
```

as an option. Despite getting a an error message, "ImportError: No module named 'cuffinks'" when running 
     python setup.py py2app,
the final app opened when double clicking.